# Qt - Android app crashes immediately

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to run an android app, I wrote in C++ using Qt, on my smartphone.

I am able to deploy the app and start running. But it immediately shuts down, without any error message or whatsoever on my phone. This is however what I can see in my Qt IDE for the Application output:

```
Starting remote process.I/ActivityManager(  764): Start proc org.qtproject.example.android for activity org.qtproject.example.android/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity: pid=16671 uid=10112 gids={50112, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi-v7a
I/art     (16671): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/art     (16671): VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:16671
I/QtCore  (16671): Start
I/Qt      (16671): qt start
D/Atlas   (16671): Validating map...
D/FindExtension(16671): FindExtension: before mHardwareRenderer.initialize, mSurface.isValid() = true
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020 - CR771817 ()
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): Build Date: 03/04/15 Wed
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): Local Branch:
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno-EGL(16671): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
I/InputMethodManagerService(  764): Enable input method client, pid=16671
I/InputMethodManagerService(  764): Disable input method client, pid=16671
I/ActivityManager(  764): Recipient 16671
E/InputEventReceiver( 1202): Looper::removeFd(71) is failed, result(0), input channel 'ClientState{37476efb uid 10112 pid 16671} (c)'
D/Process (  764): killProcessQuiet, pid=16671
I/ActivityManager(  764): Process org.qtproject.example.android (pid 16671) has died


"org.qtproject.example.android" died.
```

This also happens when I just deploy a blank project, which only contains a pushbutton which I put using Qtcreator.

This is my bugreport: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ven5pby2dy3x4uw/bugreport-2017-08-31-09-34-57.txt?dl=0

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Qt and Android are you testing with? Also are you using Qt Widgets or QML for the UI?

Comment: @xander Qtcreator 4.3.1 based on Qt 5.9.1 and Android sdk version 26 (I am not 100% sure for the latter)

Comment: Qt Creator is just the IDE, you can use many different Qt versions to compile your app so it might not be the same version (look at the build settings in Qt creator how your app is actually compiled). If you're not sure what Android version you're using you can see it on the device/emulator in the settings app at least. And one more thing, I guess your App is ARM based and not compiled as x86 (there are x86 Android versions, but most device CPU's are ARM based). It's a little bit more complicated when using native code compared to Java. :D